# Logic App Add Forwarad Slash("/") when calling API Request in body

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am calling API as per image below ,somehow logic app add forward slash for each object in body when sending POST request.

Any idea how to fix this

{
"uri": https://test.com/apicall,
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Cookie": "83B88D348F25",
"whitespace": "no"
},
"body": "request=&{\"action\":\"AddProduct\",\"ProductDetails\":{\"Prodct_Type\":"",\"Prouct\":\"apple\"}}"
}

**Body should be when sending request from logic app **
"body": "request=&{"action":"AddProduct","ProductDetails":{"Prodct_Type":"","Prouct":"apple"}}"

[image: API Call Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something simple like using an expression to replace it:

```
replace(string(body('Get_blob_content')), '\', '')
```

How to: [image]

described on this post: [How to remove or prevent escape slashes from json-file data in azure logic app workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58951351/how-to-remove-or-prevent-escape-slashes-from-json-file-data-in-azure-logic-app-w)

but do you need to pass the whole json as a parameter?
You can use the parse json action and this will let you pass the values as parameters:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action